# Using Swift's Decodable on iOS userInfo

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, codable, decodable

iOS returns json data from background notifications with the type `[AnyHashable : Any]`.
Is there any way to parse that into an struct that implements the Codable protocol?

example :

```
// Server sends the following data via apn
{"items": [{"id": "192e7926-7891-44eb-8ca7-f795d8552e84", "text": "some text", "num": 0.7}]}
```

When receiving the data on th eapp side

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
   print(userInfo["items"])
}
```

the print statement give sthe following output

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x283fe80b0>(
  {
    id = "192e7926-7891-44eb-8ca7-f795d8552e84";
    num = "0.7";
    text = "Check test";
  }
))
```

I already have a matching Codable struct:

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: UUID
    let text: String
    let num: Double
}
```

Can I somehow instantiate an `Item` from a `userInfo["items"][0]`? Obviously just sending an encoded json string would already solve that but I'm interested if there is a way to decode from [AnyHashable : Any] into an `Decodable` struct.

Thanks!

Comment: There is nothing to decode. What you’re receiving  isn’t JSON, it’s a Dictionary. You can certainly turn a Dictionary into an Item, but not by way of Decodable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert the dict to JSON object using `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:`

You might need a container struct

```
struct ItemsCollection: Decodable {
    let items: [Item]
}
```

```
        let dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = your dict
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
            let itemsCollection = try JSONDecoder().decode(ItemsCollection.self, from: jsonData)
            //now access it as itemsCollection.items[0]
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

**EDIT 1:** You can always optimize the solution by avoiding the creation of new struct using

```
        let dict: [AnyHashable: Any] = userInfo["items"][0] //not sure if you would need explicit type casting here, cant debug as I dont have actual object
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict)
            let item = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: jsonData)
            //now access item
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: So it has to be encoded into data first befor it can be decoded? I hoped swift has some smart magic that allows to take the existing structure and only do the type conversions

Comment: It allows `data` to be decoded using `Decodable` objects but you cant actually decode a dictionary :) What you have is dict of type `[AnyHashable: Any]` You can either use this or as vadian showed above you can use default init provided to initiate individual properties of struct :)

Comment: Please **never** (suggest to) `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a `DecodingError` context. You'll get a meaningless generic error message. Instead always `print(error)` And `prettyPrinted` is pointless on machine level.

Comment: @vadian: Ohhh I wasnt aware of issue with `error.localizedDescription` in a Decoding context, will change it :) pretty printed point of yours makes sense as well, agreed

Comment: The `options` parameter can be omitted entirely.

Comment: @vadian: My bad ‍♂️ you are correct again It already has a default value to arguement as an empty array `options opt: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []` Just makes me wonder how much carefully you must have observed these APIs :) respect 

Answer (score 3):

Decoding an object which has already been deserialized is not very efficient.

Extract the data and create the struct instance *manually*

```
struct Item {
    let id: UUID
    let text: String
    let num: Double

    init?(dictionary: [String:Any]) {
       guard let id = dictionary["id"] as? String,
             let uuid = UUID(uuidString: id),
             let text = dictionary["text"] as? String,
             let num = dictionary["num"] as? Double else { return nil }
       self.id = uuid
       self.text = text
       self.num = num
    }
}

if let items = userInfo["items"] as? [[String:Any]], 
   let firstItem = items.first,
   let item = Item(dictionary: firstItem) {
      print(item)
}
```

Comment: well, if theres no way to convert the userInfo type into the desired structure without encoding and decoding back, I agree that doesnt seem to be efficient. But with this approach I introduce a new place where change shave to be made if the struct that I already have and use is changed. I think just sending the json as string might be the easiest maintainable and most efficient solution. thx for your answer!

Comment: Better to give Item an initializer that takes a Dictionary.

Comment: @matt that's actually quite a smart idea, thx!